# Is it safe to provide 3.3V to 1.8V I/O supply voltage?

Tags: power-supply

I want to connect a single board computer to a TFT display. The TFT has two power lines:

[image: Power lines]

I have a 3.3V supply from the SBC.

- Is it safe to use it for both power inputs (**VCI** and **IOVCC**)?
- Can I just connect directly from the SBC to these power lines?
- Or do I really need to lower the I/O voltage to 1.8?

This is just a prototype for personal use, not for a product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use the same IOVCC as what you use as the voltage levels on the IO pins. The device allows to use 3.3V IOVCC. But if the IO pins are sent with lower voltage levels then IOVCC must match that.